# How to fix weird mesh issue

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've never used blender before and just imported this fbx to find it very strange looking, like something is wrong with the lighting or shadows? Iv'e tried changing a lot of settings but am unsure of how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Please [upload your file here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so others can take a look. Without that, it's just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some sort of shiny matcap applied to this model?
Try going into edit mode and clearing any sharp edges if there are any, or try going into your object data tab and "clear custom split normals data"

Answer (score 0):

Recalculate your normals in *edit mode* with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>